# How to setup/build LibGDX + Kotlin project correctly?

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

I've downloaded gdx-setup.jar and try to build empty project with the following settings:

[image]

And here is what I get in console:

```
Generating app in C:\Users\Divelix\Desktop\test
Executing 'C:\Users\Divelix\Desktop\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon idea'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr
```

If I do not mark "Use Kotlin" it builds well, so why is that and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to build without "Use Kotlin" and then import it directly like here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libGDX-with-Kotlin

Comment: Did you have any luck? I seem to be having similar issues

Comment: Note that Kotlin 1.3 doesn't go well with gradle 2.2 (default libgdx gradle version). Upgrade your gradle if you're having build problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've finally figured out how to build project correctly with Kotlin (and if you have trouble with gradle it also will help you). Firstly, you just should to build it without "Use Kotlin" and than than edit your project build.gradle file like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.1.1'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"

    }
}
```

Also you should delete `google()` if you have it after jcenter()

In `:desktop` replace `java` with `kotlin` plugin and add `kotlin-stdlib`

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

In `:android` add `kotlin-android` plugin and `kotlin-stdlib`

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"

    }
}
```

In `:core` replace `java` with `kotlin` plugin and add `kotlin-stdlib`

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

If you have just kotlin issue it would be enough.

If you also have gradle issue like me, so open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and fix gradle version to 3.3:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```